# What is preferred: implement method with GCD inside and then just simple call, or implement method and then call it later with GCD?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, ipad, grand-central-dispatch

what's is more prefered way to write multi threaded apps. I see two ways.
Implement method with GCD inside and then just simple call (myMethodA), or just implement method and then call it with GCD? Thanks in advance.

My point:

```
ClassA / method implementation

- (void)myMethodA
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //  doSomething1
    //  doSomething2
  });
}

- (void)myMethodB
{
  //  doSomething1
  //  doSomething2

}

ClassB / method call
{
  [myClassA methodA];
  // or
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     [myClassA methodB];
  };
}
```

Comment: Unless your class/object/methods are required to run on a certain thread, let the implementation choose where they should be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal preference. Choose whichever makes the code more readable / understandable / obvious. Also, consideration of whether the code should be possible to run on the 'current' thread or whether it should always be run on a background thread. You need to design your threading configuration, describe it and then implement with that in mind. If you're calling methods between classes like in your example then I'd generally say that any threading should be handled inside that class, not inside the calling class. But that's about distribution of knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, neither.

The preferred way should be having an *object* which knowns *where* to execute its actions:

```
completion_block_t completionHandler = ^(id result) { ... };
AsyncOperation* op = [AsyncOperation alloc] initWithCompletion:completionHandler];
[op start];  // executes its actions on a private execution context
```

Then, one can wrap those AsyncOperation objects into a convenient method:

```
- (void) fetchUsersWithCompletion:(completion_block_t)completionHandler  
{
    NSDictionary* params = ...;
    self.currentOperation = [[HTTPOperation alloc] initWithParams:params
                                                      completion:completionHandler];
    [self.currentOperation start];
}
```

The client may only be interested in specifying *where* its completionHandler should be executed. The API may be enhanced as follows:

```
- (void) fetchUsersWithQueue:(NSOperationQueue*)handlerQueue 
              withCompletion:(completion_block_t)completionHandler 
{
    NSDictionary* params = ...;

    self.currentOperation = [[HTTPOperation alloc] initWithParams:params
                                                      completion:^(id result){
        // As per the documentation of HTTPOperation, the handler will be executed
        // on an _unspecified_ execution context.
        // Ensure to execute the client's handler on the specified operation queue:
        [handlerQueue:addOperationWithBlock:^{
            completionHandler(result);
        }];
    }];
    [self.currentOperation start];
}
```

The latter API can be used as this:

```
[self fetchUsersWithQueue:[NSOperation mainQueue] completion:^(id result){
    self.users = result;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Comment: A little bit complicated for me at the moment, but thanks for your answer. Will return to it later :)

Comment: Well, this is a general "idiom" and basically results in the code what @Wain has indicated and suggested.  ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper is underscoring an important point;  when implementing anything concurrent, you have to *think very carefully about your architecture*.   Concurrent programming is hard;  not only is it hard to get it right, but it is equally as hard to make it fast.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much of a difference - it just depends on what you want to do.
If you want to execute the method on different queues each time, then the `myMethodB` system is more appropriate. If, however, you always want to run the method on the same queue, then `myMethodA` will save you time writing code (you only have to write the GCD code once).